Выходит ошибка при генерации нового CRUD папки
Выходит ошибка при генерации нового CRUD папки. Пишу в терминал команду "nest g resource task --no-spec" и прилетает в терминал ошибка.

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text') Failed to
execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:resource --name=task
--no-dry-run --no-skip-import --language="ts" --source-root="src" --no-spec --no-flat --spec-file-suffix="spec"

Обновлял @nestjs/cli, @nestjs/schematics. Ставил как разные версии так и последние. Не работает даже при пустом проекте (только что созданном)
